# How to write frontend (angularjs) to backend (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So I'm hitting my head against the wall with this:

**SERVER.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

const polls = [
  {
   ... 
  }
];

//Enable CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/polls', (req, res) => {
  let result = {polls:polls.map(function(p){
    return {id: p.id, title: p.title};
  })};
  res.json(result);
});


app.get('/polls/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id-1;
  res.json(polls[id]);
});

const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 8081;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server listening  port %s", port);
});
```

So why isn't the part `app.use(express.static(...))` not working? I've tried something like this:

**CONTROLLE.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
  console.log("hello");


  var polls = function() {
    $http.get('/polls').then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = response;
    });
  };
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title>myapp</title>
  <meta
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../server.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I can't even get the `console.log("hello")` out. Any help? I would appreciate if someone would tell me how to do this without writing the `app.use(express.static...)` in the `server.js`. Or is it even possible to get the result-map out without adding the `express.static` (or anything else to the `server.js`)?

And how can I get this working by just writing node `server.js` to my git bash?

Comment: I don't see any line of code to start your `server`. ?

Comment: Thanks for  response, but what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you need to start your server to serve files etc. Something like `app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))`

Comment: Oh, sorry! I forgot to paste it!

Comment: Good. How are you accessing your server in browser ? to see the output you want ?

Comment: can you please post your `html` file too ? for that angularjs module you just mentioned above ?

Comment: I'm writin node server.js to the command window.

Comment: running `node server.js` will just turn on your server. Angular will run in your browser. So, hit something like `localhost:port` in your server. and check console, I mean browser's console

Comment: Well yeah, I'm writing this localhost:port8081/polls and seeing the json the server.js is sending.

Comment: yeah that's Ok. what else do you want ?

Comment: I want to write a frontend for the json. And I'm not getting that working.

Comment: Should I run the controller.js instead of the server.js?

Comment: check my answer. that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the way to get what you want.

1. Name your HTML file as `index.html`
2. Put it in `public` directory
3. Place your `controller.js` file in public directory as well
4. Remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="../server.js"></script>` from index.html you don't want your server side file to client.
5. Now when you'll access `localhost:port` you should get your `index.html` file served in browser automatically and you'll have to call those APIs on your serverside manually from angularjs controller in the same way you are calling `/polls`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Now I can see the html and controller.js files in the localhost:port/8081. But how can I get the html to be visible in the localhost:port/8081/polls?

Comment: Hi! I still don't get it. I tried using routers and all, but should I use them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your static files on express. For this open the port and specify directory of your static files.

This code listens the port(3000) to serve files which under public directory. index.html should be in public directory. And you need to specify your javascript file which includes angularjs using  tags.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

// Define the port to run on
app.set('port', 3000);

// Listen for requests
let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), onHttpConnection);

function onHttpConnection(req, res){
    console.log("starting on " + server.address().port);
}
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Hi! I just added a snippet of code to the end, where the port is set. The problem is that I can't edit the server.js.